# What are all the film references in 'Me and Earl and the Dying Girl'?

Tags: reference, me-and-earl-and-the-dying-girl

[Me and Earl and the Dying Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2582496/combined) contains many low-budget parodies of classic films and I'm trying to list all the references in it. IMDb mentions some, but they're not all there [It's missing 8 1/2 (Fellini), The Seventh Seal (Bergman) and The Third Man (Welles) for example]. Does anyone know what all of them were?

Comment: I believe there are 21, as that is how many shorts they filmed for the movie, but a few articles reference that there were 42 total, but not all were actually in the movie.

Comment: @Walt I didn't know I needed 15 rep to upvote an answer :-/

Comment: This question deserves more upvotes, which would also solve your rep problem. ;) But people may have been deterred by this because it seemed too broad. I edited it emphasizing the *parodies* in this film, but if this is too intrusive, please tell me.

Comment: Lots other references in posters/scripts/books/on TV etc: Andrei Rublev, Aguirre Wrath of God, Hard Boiled, Chungking Express, Sunday Bloody Sunday, that Harold Lloyd film where he hangs off a clock, Battleship Potemkin, Brazil... many more I suspect.

Comment: There is also this one part where Rachel wore a wig while watching Earl and Greg's film. Wig was pink and resembles a lot like Natalie Portman's wig in Closer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, an article had collected all the 47(!) [Sweded](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Sweded) films in this movie. [It also has some pictures](http://www.littlewhitelies.co.uk/features/articles/me-and-earl-and-the-dying-girl-parody-films-30542). Kudos to the article's author David Ehrlich for spotting them all. These Sweded films are:

> 1. [Anatomy of a Burger](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/12/ed/6d50464443a6b972861f5ff908e8/anatomy-of-burger.jpg) ([***Anatomy of a Murder***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052561/combined), Otto Preminger, 1959)
> 2. [Ate 1/2 (Of My Lunch)](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/ea/dc/ea5b9cc94c9da5018320aa0bc056/ate-half-lunch.jpg) ([***8 1/2***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056801/combined), Federico Fellini, 1963)
> 3. A Box O’Lips, Wow ([***Apocalypse Now***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056801/combined), Francis Ford Coppola, 1979)
> 4. The Battle of All Deer ([***The Battle of Algiers***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0058946/combined), Gillo Pontecorvo, 1966)
> 5. [Breathe Less](http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:file:http:shared:mtv.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/BreatheLess-1433882435.jpg?quality=0.85&format=jpg&width=480) ([***Breathless***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053472/combined), Jean-Luc Godard, 1960)
> 6. Brew Vervet ([***Blue Velvet***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090756/combined), David Lynch, 1986)
> 7. Burden of Screams ([***Burden of Dreams***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083702/combined), Les Blank, 1982)
> 8. Can’t Tempt ([***Contempt***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057345/combined), Jean-Luc Godard, 1963)
> 9. Crouching Housecat, Hidden Housecat ([***Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0190332/combined), Ang Lee, 2000)
> 10. Death in Tennis ([***Death in Venice***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067445/combined), Luchino Visconti, 1971)
> 11. [My Dinner with Andre the Giant](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/53/b4/231af54f4362b84a1738713f2d2e/my-dinner-andre-giant.jpg) ([***My Dinner with Andre***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082783/combined), Louis Malle, 1981)
> 12. [Don’t Look Now, Because a Creepy-Ass Dwarf is About to Kill You!!! Damn.](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/51/71/dab874744108a386d65fd39f0ec1/dont-look-now-dwarf.jpg) ([***Don’t Look Now***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069995/combined), Nicolas Roeg, 1973)
> 13. [Eyes Wide Butt](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/09/29/hugo_chavez_caption_contest/Earl_fixed_big_screengrab.png.CROP.promovar-mediumlarge.png) ([***Eyes Wide Shut***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120663/combined), Stanley Kubrick, 1999)
> 14. Hairy, Old and Mod ([***Harold and Maude***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067185/combined), Hal Ashby, 1971)
> 15. La Gelee ([***La Jetèe***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056119/combined), Chris Marker, 1962)
> 16. Gone with My Wind ([***Gone with the Wind***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0031381/combined), Victor Fleming, 1939)
> 17. Gross Encounters of the Turd Kind ([***Close Encounters of the Third Kind***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075860/combined), Steven Spielberg, 1977)
> 18. [Grumpy Cul-de-sacs](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/62/6b/3d8cd82841539b4fa3d587df7b6e/grumpy-cul-de-sacs.jpg) ([***Mean Streets***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070379/combined), Martin Scorsese, 1973)
> 19. It’s a Punderful Life ([***It’s a Wonderful Life***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/combined), Frank Capra, 1946)
> 20. The Janitor of Oz ([***The Wizard of Oz***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032138/combined), Victor Fleming, 1939)
> 21. The Lady Manishness ([***The Lady Vanishes***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0030341/combined), Alfred Hitchcock, 1938)
> 22. [Monorash](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/2c/ff/8930fa3642618e127e837962379e/monorash.jpg) ([***Rashomon***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0042876/combined), Akira Kurosawa, 1950)
> 23. [My Best Actor is Also a Dangerous Lunatic](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/d8/c2/9dcf95f44a5d97e3d41574f2e298/best-actor-lunatic.jpg) ([***My Best Fiend***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200849/combined), Werner Herzog, 1999)
> 24. [Nose Ferret 2](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/09/29/hugo_chavez_caption_contest/Earl_fixed_big_screengrab.png.CROP.promovar-mediumlarge.png) ([***Nosferatu***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0013442/combined), FW Murnau, 1922)
> 25. Pittsburghasqatsi ([***Koyaanisqatsi***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085809/combined), Godfrey Reggio, 1982)
> 26. Pooping Tom ([***Peeping Tom***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054167/combined), Michael Powell, 1960)
> 27. The Prunes of Wrath ([***The Grapes of Wrath***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0032551/combined), John Ford, 1940)
> 28. Raging Bullsh*t ([***Raging Bull***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081398/combined), Martin Scorsese, 1980)
> 29. Rear Wind ([***Rear Window***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0047396/combined), Alfred Hitchcock, 1954)
> 30. [Rosemary Baby Carrots](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/a4/43/e4a14a5d49a495ed03460c99f2b5/rosemary-baby-carrots.jpg) ([***Rosemary’s Baby***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063522/combined), Roman Polanski, 1968)
> 31. Scabface ([***Scarface***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023427/combined), Howard Hawks and Richard Rosson, 1932)
> 32. Second (Helpings of Dinner) ([***Seconds***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060955/combined), John Frankenheimer, 1966)
> 33. [Senior Citizen Cane](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/34/93/934085e34a94ac99a1f283491ca6/senior-citizen-cane.jpg) ([***Citizen Kane***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033467/combined), Orson Welles, 1941)
> 34. [The Seven Seals](http://cdn.newsapi.com.au/image/v1/external?url=http%3A%2F%2Fm.wsj.net%2Fvideo%2F20150626%2F062615film7seals%2F062615film7seals_1280x720.jpg&width=650&api_key=kq7wnrk4eun47vz9c5xuj3mc) ([***The Seventh Seal***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050976/combined), Ingmar Bergman, 1957)
> 35. [A Sockwork Orange](http://mtv.mtvnimages.com/uri/mgid:file:http:shared:mtv.com/news/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SockworkOrange-1433882416.jpg?quality=0.85&format=jpg&width=480) ([***A Clockwork Orange***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066921/combined), Stanley Kubrick, 1971)
> 36. The Complete Lack of Conversation ([***The Conversation***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071360/combined), Francis Ford Coppola, 1974)
> 37. The Last Crustacean of Christ ([***The Last Temptation of Christ***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095497/combined), Martin Scorsese, 1988)
> 38. [The Rad Shoes](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/09/29/hugo_chavez_caption_contest/Earl_fixed_big_screengrab.png.CROP.promovar-mediumlarge.png) ([***The Red Shoes***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0040725/combined), Michael Powell and Emeric Pressburger, 1948)
> 39. [The Turd Man](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/09/29/hugo_chavez_caption_contest/Earl_fixed_big_screengrab.png.CROP.promovar-mediumlarge.png) ([***The Third Man***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0041959/combined), Carol Reed, 1949)
> 40. [The 400 Bros](http://d1oi7t5trwfj5d.cloudfront.net/5b/40/feb498d641fa8a82a2d714034868/400-bros.jpg) ([***The 400 Blows***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0053198/combined), François Truffaut, 1959)
> 41. Um ([***M***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0022100/combined), Fritz Lang, 1931)
> 42. [Vere’d He Go?](http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/blogs/browbeat/2011/09/29/hugo_chavez_caption_contest/Earl_fixed_big_screengrab.png.CROP.promovar-mediumlarge.png) ([***Vertigo***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052357/combined), Alfred Hitchcock, 1958)
> 43. Wages for Beer ([***The Wages of Fear***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046268/combined), Henri-Georges Clouzot, 1953)
> 44. Yellow Submarine Sandwich ([***Yellow Submarine***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0063823/combined), George Dunning, 1968)
> 45. ZZZ ([***Z***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065234/combined), Costa-Gavras, 1969)
> 46. [2:48PM Cowboy](http://imgs.littlewhitelies.co.uk/uploads/2015/06/Me-and-Earl-3.jpg) ([***Midnight Cowboy***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064665/combined), John Schlesinger, 1969)
> 47. 49th Parallelogram ([***49th Parallel***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0033627/combined), Michael Powell, 1941)